# Put it away in a place that it won’t be (damaged / harmed / hurt)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs, word-difference

Please suppose that a worker who is living in a factory has a very valuable stamp album (no matter precious or not the worker loves it for some personal reasons). He decides to travel to his hometown for a while and take some rest. Before he leaves the factory, whereas he has a very reliable friend and coworker, he asks his friend to take care of that album while he is away. Before his departure, he tells the friend:

> - Just please put it away in a place that it won’t ...........

Which one of the following words can be used here naturally:

a) be damaged

b) be harmed

c) be hurt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "natural" choice here is ***damaged*** ([to damage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/damage) = *reduce the value or usefulness of*).

***Hurt*** is completely unacceptable in OP's context. Normally, only things capable of suffering pain can be hurt.

***Harmed*** is credible, but relatively unlikely in this exact context. It tends to imply ***deliberately*** damaged.

Comment: Overall, a good answer, although I would also point out that we also use *hurt* metaphorically sometimes, as in ["his chances were hurt"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="his+chances+were+hurt").  But I agree that in this case it doesn't sound natural.  The question of when we use *hurt/harmed/damaged* is actually fairly subtle.

Comment: I was pretty sure there *would* be contexts where ***hurt*** could be used "naturally" (though probably not "literally") in reference to inanimate/insensate things. But offhand I couldn't think of a good one, which is why I settled for including ***normally*** above.  Yours is an excellent example though, so I trust the mods won't delete it in some future frenzy of "comment-tidying".